# How edit a pojo in spring java?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I want to edit a user, should I replace it with another user? Or should I just replace the attributes?

I have this controller

```
@PostMapping("/edit")
    public ResponseEntity<User> editUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        log.info("EDIT");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(userServiceImpl.editUser(user), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

this my service:

```
public User editUser(User user) {
        User owner = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
        owner=user;

        userRepository.save(user);

        return owner;
    }
```

the class User is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
```

I need to do something like that, I mean do an insert query to the bd?

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.firstname = ?1, u.lastname = ?2 where u.id = ?3")
void setUserInfoById(String firstname, String lastname, Integer userId);
```

Comment: Take a look again at jpa entity states and java object reference please.

Comment: First why do need to edit entity?

Comment: @thanhngo you should 
explain a little more, I do not understand you

Comment: @Deadpool i need edit perfil of user

Comment: `Entity` should always reflect the table and it's not a good idea to change it as you required @yaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it clear.
Let think this simple.

1. You have userRepository.save(user);
   What will it do?

   - If this object don't have an Id ~> Save it as new object
   - If this user HAD an ID, it will check OVERWRITE if the id is EXIT
     So if you wanna Edit just SOME FIELDS, let do like convention

   domain:port/user/{userId}/ (PUSH) and give some field need to change here.
   ~> Get the real obj in DB ~> update the object and do with SAVE.
   / ~> Or you can do the query update directly if you want

Answer (score 0):

Just save updated user

```
public User editUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

It will be enough.

Comment: but that would not be a new creation?

Comment: @yaha, if user has ID - corresponding user will be updated. If user ID == null - new record will be created.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will ensure that no data is lost and a new record is not generated.

```
public User editUser(User user) {
        User owner = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
        if(user.getName != null){
          owner.setName(user.getName);
        }
        if(user.getPassword != null){
          owner.setPassword(user.getPassword);
        }
        if(user.getEmail != null){
          owner.setEmail(user.getEmail);
        }
        return userRepository.save(owner);
    }
```